# in HTML, div tag how to replace line breaks and tab space/space bar with white space

Tags: html, line-breaks

```
<div class="edit" style="text-overflow: ellipsis; 
                                    font-size: 16px;
                                     width: 200px;">
      <div ng-attr-id="{{smthing.id}}" contenteditable="true"{{smthing.comment}} 
        </div>
</div>
```

When user types in line break or a tab space,it is getting saved as either 
 tags or &nbsp along with the text instead of white spaces.Thanks!
it appears like this:

```
test1`"&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br></div><div><br><div><br></div>"`
```

Comment: do you want to change the behavior of tab space to replace with white space? If you have more than one field in the application, tab button will always go to next field.

Comment: i want to render the linebreaks and white-spaces as html content.If the user wants to go to next line,,content should be rendered in the next line withput the <br> tags